# Fast 32x32 bit multiply on ARM M0

Tags: performance, c, integer, assembly, embedded

I have a time-critical calculation running on an ARM Cortex-M0. This is the fastest 32x32 bit -> 64 bit multiplication that I can come up with.

The following C compiles almost 1-1 to assembly instructions:

```
//consider each arg as two 16-bit parts.
//r0 is Aa is A<<16+a. r1 is Bb is B<<16+b
//then Aa * Bb = (A*B)<<32 + (a*B+A*b)<<16 + a*b
//     result  =  Hh<<32   +  KmM<<16      + Ll

uint64_t mul32x32(uint32_t r0, uint32_t r1)
    register uint32_t r2= r1&0xFFFF;  // b
    register uint32_t r3= r1>>16;     // B  
    register uint32_t r4= r0&0xFFFF;  // a
    r1 = r0 >> 16;                    // A
    r0 = r4;                // a
    r4 *= r2;               // Ll = a*b
    r0 *= r3;               // a*B
    r3 *= r1;               // Hh = B*A
    r2 *= r1;               // b*A
    r1 = 0;                 // K
    ADD_W_CARRY(r1,r0,r2);  // 0K.mM = a*B + b*A
    r1 <<= 16;              // K0
    r2 = r0 >> 16;          // 0m
    r0 <<=16;               // M0
    DBL_ADD_W_CARRY(r1,r0,r2,r4); // K0.M0 += 0m.Ll 
    r1 += r3;                     // Km += Hh
    return (((uint64_t)r1)<<32)|r0;  
}
```

It uses this bit of inline assembly, to deal with C's inability to express the carry flag:

```
//R.r+=x // clears x to avoid consuming another register
#define ADD_W_CARRY(R,r,x) __asm {\
        ADDS r,r,x;\
        MOVS x,0x0;\
        ADCS R,R,x;}
//pure C equiv is:  {r+=x;R+=(r<x);x=0;}

//R.r+=X.x
#define DBL_ADD_W_CARRY(R,r,X,x) __asm{\
        ADDS r,r,x;\
        ADCS R,R,X;}
//Pure C equiv is:  {r+=x;R+=X+(r<x); }
```

This compiles to:

> ```
> PUSH     {r4}         ;// 2
> LSRS     r3,r0,#16    ;// 1
> UXTH     r2,r1        ;// 1       
> UXTH     r0,r0        ;// 1
> MOV      r4,r0        ;// 1
> LSRS     r1,r1,#16    ;// 1
> MULS     r4,r2,r4     ;// 1
> MULS     r0,r1,r0     ;// 1
> MULS     r1,r3,r1     ;// 1
> MULS     r2,r3,r2     ;// 1
> ADDS     r0,r0,r2     ;// 1
> MOVS     r3,#0        ;// 1
> MOVS     r2,#0        ;// 1
> ADCS     r3,r3,r2     ;// 1
> LSLS     r2,r3,#16    ;// 1
> LSRS     r3,r0,#16    ;// 1
> LSLS     r0,r0,#16    ;// 1
> ADDS     r0,r0,r4     ;// 1
> ADCS     r2,r2,r3     ;// 1
> POP      {r4}         ;// 2
> ADDS     r1,r2,r1     ;// 1  
> BX       lr           ;// 3
>
>                       ;== 26 cycles
> ```

Is it possible to do better?

Comment: I fail to see how this would be faster than just 64-bit multiplication.

Comment: CortexM0 has no 64 bit multiply instruction, and the code the compiler generates from C code to do one takes 35 cycles.

Answer (score 16):

First of all, yes, CortexM0 lacks any way to do 32x32=64 multiplication in hardware. CortexM3 and CortexM4 have [the `umull` instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CIHJFABI.html), which lets you do 32x32=64 really easily.

And yes, since you're writing in C, one *possible* implementation would be

```
uint64_t mul32x32(uint32_t r0, uint32_t r1) { return r0*(uint64_t)r1; }
```

but I assume you've already tried that (with `-O3` and whatever other optimization and inlining options you can turn up) and discovered that your compiler doesn't inline the multiplication, but leaves it as a call to some internal libc function.

A quick Google search turned up [this previous StackOverflow question on exactly the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286239/fastest-cortex-m0-thumb-32x32-64-multiplication-function), where someone in the comments linked to GCC's implementation of 64x64=64 multiplication for CortexM0 [(here)](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2010-10/txt00435.txt), with the suggestion that you could constant-propagate "upper bits are known to be zero" through the whole thing by hand and that would give you something decent. I don't know if that's true.

Have you also benchmarked the "naive" approach of

```
uint64_t mul32x32(uint32_t r0, uint32_t r1)
{ 
    uint16_t r0h = r0 >> 16, r0l = r0 & 0xFFFF;
    uint16_t r1h = r1 >> 16, r1l = r1 & 0xFFFF;
    uint64_t result = (r0h * r1h);
    result <<= 16;
    result += r0h*r1l;
    result += r0l*r1h;
    result <<= 16;
    result += r0l*r1l;
    return result;
}
```

or equivalently

```
uint64_t mul32x32(uint32_t r0, uint32_t r1)
{ 
    uint16_t r0h = r0 >> 16, r0l = r0 & 0xFFFF;
    uint16_t r1h = r1 >> 16, r1l = r1 & 0xFFFF;
    return ((uint64_t)(r0h * r1h) << 32)
         + ((uint64_t)(r0h * r1l) << 16)
         + ((uint64_t)(r0l * r1h) << 16)
         + ((uint64_t)(r0l * r1l) << 0);
}
```

? As long as none of the arithmetic operations get turned into library function calls, this has the benefit of being portable ANSI C *and* being susceptible to inlining by the compiler. If you care about speed, susceptibility-to-inlining should be your #1 concern.

Since you have access to your compiler and we don't (I'm guessing Green Hills, from the `__asm{ }` syntax for inline assembly blocks?), you might get better answers if you posted the assembly that results from the above three C implementations.

Finally, note that CortexM0's `MULS` instruction [takes either 1 cycle or 32 cycles, depending on the processor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/115342/how-many-cycles-does-an-arm-cortex-m0-use-to-multiply-floats#comment258660_115346). If you're on one of those 32-cycle processors, doing four `MULS` instructions in a row is probably one of the worst things you can do. If `MULS` only takes 1 cycle, then you're probably okay; I don't *think* there's any need to space out those `MULS` instructions the way one might on a machine where they took multiple cycles ([software pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_pipelining)).

Comment: Thanks.  The compiler is the one with Keil's uVision.  The processor has 1 cycle multiply.  If I let the compiler do `uint64_t` multiplies,  it generates calls to a library routine ` __ARM_common_ll_muluu` which takes 35 cycles.  I'll test some of the other ideas soon.

Comment: The GCC implementation looks to be the same 35 cycle routine.

Comment: @AShelly Have you looked at [this version](https://github.com/bobbl/libaeabi-cortexm0/blob/master/lmul.S)?  You can eliminate 3+ instructions from this version because this one is a 64x64 multiply, so the first few instructions that operate on the high bits are unneeded.

Comment: The "naive" version compiles to 39 cycles, the "equivalent" to 38.  See [Revision 4](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/114393/revisions) for details.  @JS1's is 28 - maybe that can be trimmed as suggested.

Comment: @AShelly Since this is a 64x64 multiply, you can pretend that `r1` and `r3` start out as zero.  This allows you to remove lines 48-50 and line 55.  Then change the two `r3` on lines 52 and 54 to be `r1` to make the registers correct.  This saves 4 instructions.  However, this assumes that your inputs are in `r3:r2` and `r1:r0`.  In a 32 bit multiply, your inputs are in `r1` and `r0`.  You will need to use one extra instruction to copy `r1` to `r2`, because the code clobbers `r1` during the computation because `r1` will be one of the outputs.  So in summary, it should be 28 - 4 + 1 = 25 cycles.

Answer (score 3):

#### Attempt 1

To expand on my rather long comment above, I took the 64x64 multiply [from this library implementation on github](https://github.com/bobbl/libaeabi-cortexm0/blob/master/lmul.S), and I modified it to be a 32x32 multiply.  I'm not sure how you are counting the cycles, but this may be equivalent to your 26 cycle implementation because I count 19 "1-cycle" instructions which is the same as in the original post.  I don't know how many cycles the `push` and `pop` take.

```
@ long long mul32(long r1, long r0)
@
@ Multiply r1 and r0 and return the product in r1:r0
@
    .thumb_func
        .global mul32
mul32:

    push    {r4, lr}
    mov     r2, r1

    lsrs    r1, r0, #16
    lsrs    r4, r2, #16
    muls    r1, r4

    lsrs    r3, r0, #16
    uxth    r0, r0
    uxth    r2, r2
    muls    r3, r2
    muls    r4, r0
    muls    r0, r2

    movs    r2, #0
    adds    r3, r4
    adcs    r2, r2
    lsls    r2, #16
    adds    r1, r2

    lsls    r2, r3, #16
    lsrs    r3, #16
    adds    r0, r2
    adcs    r1, r3
    pop {r4, pc}
```

#### Attempt 2

Actually, I just transformed the above to this, which should be faster than the original post (it now has 1 fewer instructions than the previous version).  Perhaps you could test it to make sure I didn't do something wrong because I transformed the code in my head:

```
@ long long mul32(long r1, long r0)
@
@ Multiply r1 and r0 and return the product in r1:r0
@
    .thumb_func
        .global mul32
mul32:

    push    {r4, lr}

    uxth    r2, r1
    lsrs    r3, r0, #16
    lsrs    r1, r1, #16
    mov     r4, r1
    muls    r1, r3

    uxth    r0, r0
    muls    r3, r2
    muls    r4, r0
    muls    r0, r2

    movs    r2, #0
    adds    r3, r4
    adcs    r2, r2
    lsls    r2, #16
    adds    r1, r2

    lsls    r2, r3, #16
    lsrs    r3, #16
    adds    r0, r2
    adcs    r1, r3
    pop {r4, pc}
```

Comment: Thanks.  `push` and `pop` take 1 + count(registers) cycles, so 3 in these two instances.  In attempt 2, you seem to be missing a `mov r4,r1` right before the `muls r1,r3`, to prevent using an uninitialized register.     With that addition, it is 24 cycles.    It is performing the  same set of operations, except I had an extra `mov  r3,#0` that this one avoids.  The other difference is the return to caller method:  `push {r4,lr}...pop {r4,pc}` is 6 cycles vs`push {r4}...pop{r4};bx lr` which is 7.

Comment: @AShelly You're right.  I fixed up attempt #2 to add in the missing `mov r4, r1` that you spotted.

Answer (score 0):

In some conditions your code returns incorrect output....check attempt 2 for following inputs : `-1` and `-1`

r1:r0 should return 0x00000000,0x00000001

Comment: You are multiplying 0xFFFF,FFFF and 0xFFFF,FFFF. Now check again. Groetjes Albert

Comment: Is this a review of the code in the question, or is a comment on [JS1's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/118838/75307) which introduces "attempt 2"?

Comment: The inputs are `uint32_t`, so `-1` isn't possible (except as the bit-pattern for UINT_MAX).  Squaring it doesn't produce `1`, it produces `0xfffffffe` : `0x00000001`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that some implementations of the M0 core take 32 cycles to perform a multiply, using the minimal number of MULS is important. Now, the bottom 32 bits are correctly calculated by 1 MULS so only 3 MULS are strictly necessary. If only r0-r3 are used, that is another 4 cycles (stack unstack) and seeing as a multiply will be the bottom subroutine, lr (r14) only needs to be stacked if your code intends to use it. If you are *THAT* short of registers and can prevent interrupts, you can use store sp (r13) as well.

The problem lies with the fact that only the Z & N flags are updated by MULS. I'm stumbling with the way to detect an overflow in an elegant manner. Can someone more able than I devise an elegant solution?

Comment: Can you please sketch *how* to produce the correct 64 bit result using just the `3 MULS [] strictly necessary`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCbZayFr9RE

1-if you often read from a table (<256 entries), place at bottom of ROM i.e. from $00000000. Doing this made my 14-16 cycle CLZ (count leading zeros) to 12-14 cycles. Address is an immediate!

2-interrupts swap the register file in the CPU of M0/M0+/M1 so feel free to push the LR & store SP in RAM. SP has powerful instructions and addressing modes. Base all code on SP addressing.

3-Ask ARM community. They are great. If you work out why the LSxx instructions use bits 0-7 rather 0-4 of register is unknown by ARM so if you work it out, post.